# What is the differential emission measure (DEM)? what are its physical significant in solar plasma?

Tags: observational-astronomy, resource-request, solar-flare

I'm trying to understand what differential emission measure (DEM) is, especially its physical significant in solar plasma.

Is it possible to give a short description and perhaps suggest to me some paper(s) or book(s) related to DEM that go further?

Comment: I've edited the question slightly; it certainly seems ripe for fact-based answers and I can't understand why someone would vote to block answers because it "is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations." **voting to leave open!**

Comment: The last 15 words make it VTC for me. Answering with description and explanation would be great, though.